# <input type="datetime-local" /> not displaying the TIME as expected

Tags: javascript, html, datetime

I've been trying to display a datetime in a input box and based on the code snippet below one would think that the text input and datetime-local input would display the same time. But alas, they do not.

Can anyone tell me why, and how I can get it to behave as it "should"?

Image of how it behaves on several of computers I have tested.

[image: picture of the wierd behaviour]

```js
const datetime = document.getElementById('datetime');
const expected = document.getElementById('expected');
const date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0)
datetime.valueAsNumber = date;
expected.value = date.toLocaleString();
```

```html
<h1> Datetime-local bug: </h1>
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" />
<input type="text" id="expected" />
```

Comment: I see the same time in both inputs. What browser are you using? I'm using Chrome.

Comment: What browser, not every browser supports it? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local#browser_compatibility

Comment: im using chrome, ill add a screenshot of how it looks when i try to use it.

Comment: `valueAsNumber` is read-only. Use `value = date.toISOString()`

Comment: @HereticMonkey `valueAsDate` is `get/set` - I recommend using that instead.

Comment: @Barmar - I see the same behavior in Safari 15.1 - but it is very clear that this is not at all consistently supported by browsers. [Reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/datetime-local)

Comment: This--->"_**Can anyone tell me why, and how I can get it to behave as it "should"?**_" - you can't. This feature is browser implementation dependent. It is recommended you separate the date and time inputs or use a UI framework of some type if this is a requirement for your project.

Comment: @Dai Not in all browsers. When I tried in Edge, it threw an error. Uncaught InvalidStateError: Failed to set the 'valueAsDate' property on 'HTMLInputElement': This input element does not support Date values.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a number of inconsistencies with how browsers render and parse the value of `input type="datetime-local"`. In general, it's best to use separate controls for date and time and combine them behind the scenes as needed (perhaps along with time zone information for accurate DST tracking).

For this question, however, the `valueAsNumber` property is read-only according the the specification. Some browsers have implemented this differently, as they have the `valueAsDate` property, which should be writeable.

Run the following snippet in Edge Version 95.0.1020.53 (Official build) (64-bit) on Windows 10 and it will likely throw an error regarding the input not supporting `Date` values.

```js
const datetime = document.getElementById('datetime');
const expected = document.getElementById('expected');
const date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0)
datetime.valueAsDate = date;
expected.value = date.toLocaleString();
```

```html
<h1> Datetime-local bug: </h1>
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" />
<input type="text" id="expected" />
```

Thus, I suggest setting the `value` property to an abbreviated **ISO 8601** format (without fractions of seconds, and without time zone).

```js
const datetime = document.getElementById('datetime');
const expected = document.getElementById('expected');
const date = new Date();
date.setMilliseconds(0)
datetime.value = date.toISOString().slice(0, 19);
console.log(datetime.value);
expected.value = date.toLocaleString();
```

```html
<h1> Datetime-local bug: </h1>
<input type="datetime-local" id="datetime" />
<input type="text" id="expected" />
```

Note that the formats will not necessarily be the same. This is due to `input type="datetime-local"` using the custom regional settings of the OS, while `Date.prototype.toLocaleString` not using those settings. For instance, I prefer to using yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss format (e.g., 2021-11-16 17:46:33) for dates and times, but my language (what some are determined to call "locale") is set as "en-US", which means `toLocaleString` wants to format in MM/dd/yyyy h:mm:ss aa format (e.g., 11/16/2021 12:46:33 PM).

Comment: thank you for a comprehensive answer, I need to rethink how I want to implement this then!

Comment: In Safari 15, in both the OP and this answer, *#datetime* is set to the UTC date and time, not local. Strongly agree with "*…language (what some are determined to call "locale")*". ;-)

Comment: @RobG Yeah, I was wondering if I should elongate my answer with that UTC wrinkle too. If I'm not mistaken, Safari would do the same thing with `new Date(date.toISOString().slice(0, 19))`... Browsers and Dates, man, browsers and Dates.